# What is the use of UML in day today life?

Tags: excel, oop, uml

I don't have a programming job. But I do code (using functional programming and OOP) from time to time, in order to make many repetitive tasks, that I perform in the software I use, simple: extract data from a simulation and dump it into an excel file, read data from an excel file and use that data to manipulate my simulation, etc.

I can manage this pretty well without using UML. But what I want to know is: for someone who doesn't code for a living, yet uses code to make life simpler and save time, how important is using UML (I do understand that I cannot use it for functional programming)? What are the practical benefits? How can I write better code by using UML? I know it's not a substitute for a programming language .. as in I cannot use it as a programming language. But what I was also hoping to understand was how can I use it before I actually begin to write OOP code?

Comment: while you are not a programmer, and you don't work with a team, UML is not kinda useful for you, even in team works, the actual code writer(developer) don't know about the UML, UML is a engineering thing.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike other answers suggest I believe that UML is not only beneficial when you work with a team of developers, also when you work on a project on your own you can benefit by using UML.

In my opinion the true benefit of UML is that you are forced to think before you act. Of course you can always directly start programming when starting a new project, but (most certainly for larger projects) it is better to think about your design.

By creating complete UML models you will notice that you need to think about your software (what does the user needs to be able to do with my software? How will the software react? etc. etc.). Due to this whole process I believe that by the time you will start coding, you will already have such good understanding on the structure of your program that you will be able to code your project better and faster.

Concluding I think UML is all about doing it right the first time.

Next to this, you will always have proper documentation on your code. This makes it more easy to maintain.

Comment: +1, to me this is the best answer. As it (implicitly) shows that UML is a tool to design and engineer software.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what you mean by day to day life but [UML helps](http://www.dthomas.co.uk/dtalm/products/technologies/why-use-uml.htm) in:

> - The communication of the desired structure and behaviour of a system    between analysts, architects, developers, stakeholders and
>     users.
> - The visualisation and control of system architecture.
> - Promote a deeper understanding of the system, exposing opportunities    for simplification and re-use.
> - Manage risk.

Answer (score 0):

When working in a team, you first create a UML. That way you know which classes have to be made and you can divide the working, knowing everyone will use the names on the UML with the right connections between classes. (Inheritance, composition,..)

It's an abstract version of a program and it's very important. Ofcourse, if you're on your own you don't 'need' to use it, but it might make life easier. If the task takes long, create the UML beforehand so you don't loose track of what you're doing plus it helps you see design patterns. :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other mentioned use cases of UML models, the most efficient use case for a UML model is when it is used to generate other models or text (code).

For instance you can generate java classes from a UML class diagram.

Search for MDA (Model Driven Architecture) or MDSD (Model Driven Software Design).

If you are looking for a tool to support generating code/text from UML models then take a look at the [Acceleo Project](http://www.eclipse.org/acceleo/).